# Issue with peer dependencies

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying to use `@material-ui/pickers` in my react project. I got warnings to install peer dependencies and I did. However, there is one dependency warning that is persistent. [I install it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@date-io/core). But I still get the warning:

> npm WARN @material-ui/pickers@3.2.10 requires a peer of
> @date-io/core@^1.3.6 but none is installed. You must install peer
> dependencies yourself.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to install this package the dependent  `npm i @date-io/core@^1.3.6`

Answer (score 1):

I solved by specifying the exact version and add `--save`:

```
npm i @date-io/core@^1.3.6 --save
```